# unexpected different sizes returned from glGetRenderbufferParameteriv in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

Hello I am writing an example OpenGLES app, if I setup openGL via the view's `initWithCode:(NSCoder *) coder` method, the call of
    `glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_backingWidth);`
returns 960x480 for iPad air.

But if I setup openGL in the view's `-(void) layoutSubviews` method, it will return 2048x1536,

I can not understand why they return different. can any expert explain?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. the original size is from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You need add [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context] before all openGL operation. In my case, it's fixed. Good luck!